# What is the solution of this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Lat $(a,b,c)\in S^2$, where $S^2:=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb R^3: x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1 \}$. How to solve the following system of equations:
$$
 x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2=a,\\
2(yz+xt)=b,\\
2(yt-xz)=c,\\
x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1
$$
with unknown $x,y,z,t \in \mathbb R$.

Edit.
The queston was edited. I added the last equation
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1.
$$

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: are you searching for real solutions?

Comment: @ Alex You must have 4 equations.

Comment: @user258250 I think the 4th is given by $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Comment: @Alex Doesn't seem to be very easy to solve. Also, add the definition of $S$ to your question

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ gives a simpler result of the given system

Comment: what does it mean now?

Answer (score 2):

Assume first that $a \neq -1$.

By the 1. and 4. equation we have
$$
x^2+y^2=\frac{a+1}{2}.
$$
Then
$$
x=\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}}\cos \phi,\\
y=\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}} \sin \phi,
$$
where $\phi$ is an arbitrary numer such that  $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$.
By the 2. and 3. equations we have
$$
2\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}} (\sin \phi) z+2\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}} (\cos \phi) t=b,\\
-2\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}} (\cos \phi) z +2\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{2}} (\sin \phi) t=c.
$$
This gives
$$
z=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2(a+1)} }b \sin \phi-\frac{1}{\sqrt {2(a+1)} }c \cos \phi, \\
t=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2(a+1)} }b \cos \phi +\frac{1}{\sqrt {2(a+1)} } \sin \phi.
$$

Assume now that $a=-1$. By the same method as above we obtain:
$$
x=0,y=0, z=\cos \phi, t=\sin \phi,
$$
where $\phi$ is an arbitrary numer such that $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$.